# Java:Variance Issue in Simulation

Tags: java, class, object, simulation, variance

I recently wrote a little simulation and am having trouble finding the variance, my class is as follows:

```
    class aQuarter {
    public int ordered; 
    public int leftOver;
    public int profit;
    public int profit2;
    public double variance;
    public int demand;
    public int demandTotal;
    public int counter;
    public int sold;
    public int averageProfit;
    public double standardDev;
    public int soldTotal;
    public int orderedTotal;



    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
    public void incrementCounter() { //increments the counter for every week
        counter++;
    }
    public int getDemand() {
        return demand;
    }
    public void setDemand(int demand) { //sets the demand and adds that demand to the total demand for stat keeping
        this.demand = demand;
        demandTotal+=demand;
    }
    public int getDemandAverage() {
        return demandTotal/counter; //returns the average demand
    }
    public int getProfitAverage() {
        return profit/counter;     //returns the average profit
    }

    public int getOrderedAverage() { //returns how many ordered on average for that quarter
        return orderedTotal/counter;
    }
    public void setOrdered(int ordered) { //sets how much was ordered
        this.ordered = ordered;
        orderedTotal+=ordered;
    }
    public int getleftOver() { //testing purposes
        return leftOver;
    }
    public void setleftOver() { //sets how many gallons we have left over to deduct from the profit made
        int x=ordered-demand; 
        if (x<0) {              //if the demand was more than we ordered, none leftover
            leftOver=0;
        }
        else
            leftOver=x;         //if we ordered more than was demanded, leftover = ordered-demand

    }
    public int getSoldAverage() {
        return soldTotal/counter; //returns how many was sold average
    }
    public void setSold() {
        int x = ordered-demand;
        if (x<=0) {             //sets how many we sold
            sold=ordered;       //if the demand was more than we ordered, we sold how much was demanded
            soldTotal+=sold;    //add that total to the soldTotal accumulator
        }
        else {
            sold=demand;        //else, we ordered more than was demanded, making us sell how much was demanded
            soldTotal+=sold;    //add that total to the soldTotal accumulator
        }

    }
    public int getProfit() {
        return profit;
    }
    public void setProfit() {               //sets the profit made for the week
        int baseProfit=sold*10 - leftOver*7;  
        profit+= sold*10 - leftOver*7;      //For every gallon we sold, we made 10 dollars,but for every gallon that
        profit2+=(baseProfit*baseProfit);   //was leftover, we lost 7 dollars
    }                                       //add the profit squared to profit2

    public double getVariance() {           //gets the variance of the simulation for the quarter
        averageProfit=profit/counter;
        variance=profit2/counter -averageProfit*averageProfit;
        return variance;
    }
    public double getStandardDev() {        //gets the standard deviation for the quarter
        standardDev=Math.sqrt(variance);
        return standardDev;
    }

}
```

And the calls to the class that are in the "for" time loop.

```
            firstQuarter.incrementCounter(); //add 1 to the counter
            firstQuarter.setOrdered(50+gallonsDelivered()); //set how many gallons ordered for quarter+ randomness
            firstQuarter.setDemand(gallonsleftOver1()); //sets demand using the demands for the first quarter
            firstQuarter.setSold(); //sets sold
            firstQuarter.setleftOver(); //sets how many leftover to deduct from the profit made
            firstQuarter.setProfit(); //sets the profit
```

Everything is printing out as expected, except the variance which is giving me out of this world figures.

```
For Quarter 1:
 Average Profit Per Week: 444
 Average Demand Per Week: 54
 Average Ordered Per Week: 51
 Average Sold Per Week:47
 Average Variance of Profit: 8915.0
 Standard Deviation: 94.41927769264072
```

I followed the precedure to get the variance as done in past assignments, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here and was hoping another set of eyes could lead to some answers. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why do you think the variance is wrong?  What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

All the variables you are using in your computation of the variance are `int` variables! That's the issue! Because of that, the division in your formula doesn't function as expected. Assigning to a `double` variable doesn't mean that the computations that would take place would be floating point computations. The computation is carried out as an integer computation and then implicitly cast to `double`

Comment: I changed all variables in my class to double and am still having the same problem

Comment: Really? Well what's the correct value for the scenario you have given here?

Comment: Probably in the 20's or so

Comment: Oh I see.. Well, from a programming point of view, I can't see any other fault other than the variable issue.. Are you sure the way you compute the variance is correct? It looks ok to me, but my stat knowledge is a bit rustic though..